# How does a correlated subquery 'loop' through the outer subquery?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm having some trouble understanding just how exactly an inner subquery (that is referencing an outer subquery) works when returning a set for every row in the outer query. I know WHAT it does, but not HOW it does it.

Right now, I'm thiking of it as a "nested loop" (coming from a programmer background, but never worked with databases). But I'm having difficulties following the step-by-step logic.

See, in a typical 'for loop' in any kind of programming language I understand that the outer loop will count and perform actions that are nested. It makes a lot of sense to me. But for the tsql example below, I'm just not seeing **WHY** the inner query would 'run' for every row in the outer query. Or does it even?

```
SELECT categoryid, productid, productname, unitprice
FROM Production.Products AS P1
WHERE unitprice = 
  (SELECT MIN(unitprice)
   FROM Production.Products AS p2
   WHERE P2.categoryid = P1.categoryid);
```

Now according to the book from which this sample is taken from (using TSQL2012 database) the correlation is the predicate P2.categoryid = P1.categoryid.
And I understand it, P1.category ID will cycle through all the rows in categoryid and return the minimum unitprice for each of those.

But in my mind, I don't understand how the query determines the values that P1.categoryid is going to hold.

Comment: for each row in the outer query (that's where `P1` is), there can only be ONE value for `P1.categoryid`.  so the subquery examines only those rows in `p2` (the Products table in the subquery) where `categoryid` is the same as the `categoryid` of the single row in the outer query It is processing.  It is exactly the same as it would be for a join.  How the query processor merges the two sets of records is up tot he query processor. There are several different merge techniques available.

Comment: Okay, it makes a tiny bit more sense to me, but I'm still in the haze. 
See, when you use JOIN and specify the ON clause to say 

`t1.ID = t2.ID`

To me it makes sense, because you have a dedicated ON clause (to match rows, and a special JOIN keyword).

But with two SELECT statements, where one is nested, how can such behaviour be emulated?

Comment: Perhaps reading up on [logical query processing](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/logical-query-processing-what-it-and-what-it-means-you), which explains the order in which parts of statements are processed, will help. Or it might cause your [brain to try to escape](http://dilbert.com/strip/2016-11-30).

Comment: I'm guessing just understanding what happens will suffice for an entry level position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for each row in the outer query (that's where P1 is), there can only be ONE value for P1.categoryid. so the subquery examines only those rows in p2 (the Products table in the subquery) where categoryid is the same as the categoryid of the single row in the outer query It is processing. It is exactly the same as it would be for a join. How the query processor merges the two sets of records is up to the query processor. There are several different merge techniques available.

Effectively, since the subquery is in a where clause, it simply filters the result set to eliminate all rows where the unit price is ***not*** the lowest unit price in that category of products. i.e. it selects the lowest priced product[s] in each category.